# Пишемо з апострофом чи без "звязувати, розвязувати, пов'язати, зв'язок"?

Tags: правопис

Натрапила на таку ось статтю [http://www.ukrcenter.com/Форум/26819-6/Новий-український-правопис](http://www.ukrcenter.com/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC/26819-6/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81)
Де пишеться про "новий український правопис"... деякі слова зрозумілі а деякі ну зовсім маячня (вибачте)! 
Зокрема я про слова які пишуться з апострофом чи без нього:зв'язувати, розвязувати, пов'язати?
А слово "зв'язок" згідно цієї статті взагалі пишеться без апострофа... 
Якщо чесно я заплуталась... Допоможіть!

Comment: То не стаття, то форум. Повідомлення, на яке Ви натрапили, починається зі слів «Найголовніші правила українського правопису 5(12).07.1919». Увага: **1919**! Тобто це один із історичних укр. правописів (що застосовували чи принаймні збирались) на початку XX століття. Не відповідає нормам сучасного правопису. (Сторінка називається «Новий український правопис», тому що це початкова тема обговорення (правопис 2003 року, станом на 2003 рік він був «новим»), але, як завжди, почали про одне, закінчили про інше (Ви дали посилання на 6-ту сторінку обговорення, а не на 1-шу).)

Comment: Чинний правопис 2015: http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/pravopys2015.htm (а ще скоро має вийти правопис 2018).

Comment: Дуже дякую за посилання. Так я бачила що то форум, і що обговорення дуже давнє, мене збентежило і заплутало те, що коли я у пошуку вбила написання цих слів то чомусь випала саме ця сторінка... Тобто свіжої інформації я не побачила! Тепер завдяки посиланню на чинний правопис я знайду відповідь! Дякую!

Comment: Зазначу, що _в_ ўважалася суто твердим звуком, тому в давнину могли не писати протинку. Так само було і з словом, наприклад, _мяч_, де _м_ — теж суто твердиь звук. Залишилосӓ тїльки дати поўноцінну відповідь з ѕерелами.

Answer (score 2):

Згідно із чинним [Українським правописом](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/pravopys2015.htm) наведені Вами слова пишуться з апострофом. Таку інформацію знаходимо у [пунктах № 1 та № 3 з § 6](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par6):

> 1. Після губних приголосних (б, п, в, м, ф): б’ю, п’ять, п’є, в’язи, у здоров’ї, м’ясо, рум’яний, тім’я, мереф’янський, В’ячеслав, Стеф’юк.
>
> Примітка. Апостроф не пишеться, коли перед губним звуком є приголосний (крім р), який належить до кореня: дзвякнути, мавпячий, свято, тьмяний, цвях; але: верб’я, торф’яний, черв’як.
>
> Коли такий приголосний належить до префікса, то апостроф пишеться, як і в тих же словах без префікса: зв’язок, зв’ялити, підв’язати, розм’якшити.
>
> 3. Після префіксів та першої частини складних слів, що закінчуються на твердий приголосний: без’язикий, від’їзд, з’єднаний, з’їхати, з’явитися, об’єм, під’їхати, роз’юшити, роз’яснити; дит’ясла, пан’європейський, пів’яблука; але з власними назвами — через дефіс: пів-Європи тощо (див. § 26, п. 1, д).

Отже, аби визначити, чи потрібно ставити апостроф у слові, спершу нам слід зрозуміти, від якого слова воно походить (перепрошую за тавтологію). Далі виділяємо корінь. Аж тоді дивимось, під яке правило підпадає отримана ситуація. Наприклад, слово "зв’язок". Походить від "в’язати", корінь -в’яз-. Звертаємось до правил. Результат: пункт № 1, адже після губних приголосних (б, п, в, м, ф) перед я, ю, є, ї. Отже, апостроф ставимо!